# What is VMSystem in the Java class library?

Tags: java, jvm, class-library

In my journey to understand programming languages/compilers, I thought it might be cool to try to write small versions of the Java class library.

I decided to start with writing my own println() method. And no, not a method that simply calls println.

**My Code so far:**

```
package maintest;

import java.io.PrintStream;
import gnu.classpath.SystemProperties;
import gnu.classpath.VMStackWalker;

public class JohnSystem {

    public static final PrintStream out = VMSystem.makeStandardOutputStream();

}
```

So basically, I wrote a "new" System class. Now something funny I noticed about the OpenJDK system class. The `public static final` variable 'out' contained within `Java.lang.System` doesn't get instantiated in the way objects normally do with the new keyword. I tried to mimic the way it was done and wrote the code above accordingly.

I figured `VMSystem` was another class in the class library which had a static method `makeStandardOutputStream()` which returned a `PrintStream` object.

That would be fine except the compiler (or maybe eclipse?) doesn't recognize VMSystem and when I tried to import the packages I found at the OpenJDK, they are also not recognized.

The code I'm referring to is at:  http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/lang/System-source.html

So, basically I'm trying to find out how to be able to use the VMSystem methods. Is there maybe a package I need to download? That doesn't really make sense though. Since `System.out.println()` works, then the packages must already be there no? Or is it perhaps a permissions/security issue?

Thanks!

Comment: The `System` I/O fields [have special properties in the JLS that apply only to them](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5.4). Note _generally_ that internal code that is part of the JVM itself, such as `VMSystem`, is subject to change at any time and often by necessity uses very weird (from the Java perspective) techniques to provide the JVM platform.

Answer (score 2):

The `VMSystem` class is an internal class in the (old, virtually defunct) GNU ClassPath implementation of the Java SE class libraries.

It is not part of the Java APIs, and there is no equivalent to it in OpenJDK; i.e. the methods you are looking for may not exist.

On the other hand ... if you want to understand how OpenJDK handles JVM bootstrapping (setting up `in`, `out` and `err` for example), your best bet is to download an *actual* OpenJDK source tree, and deep-dive it.

In Java 11 for example, the initialization of `in`, `out` and `err` happens in a private method of `System` called `initPhase1()`.  Naturally, you can't call it (because it is `private`), but you can certainly look to see what it does and duplicate that in your own experiment.  But you will see that the actual assignment of the those variables happens in native code.

Finally:

> In my journey to understand programming languages/compilers, I thought it might be cool to try to write small versions of the Java class library.

I think you would be better of just *reading* the OpenJDK source code.

Comment: VG but there is nothing 'virtual' about it. The GNU CLASSPATH project stalled in March 2012 at Java 1.5 and has never progressed. It is surprising to find even a relic of it here in 2020.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne the internet never forgets. I’ve seen some questions linking to slides that were describing JVM/class loaders/etc in a way that went outdated at Java 1.1/1.2 times…